# Pinescript TradingView Backtesting Strategies with Trailing Stop Function

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to backtest a "Long" strategy in tradingview using trailing stops. For example I want to be able to open a long with a 2% target above price, a stop loss of 1% below price, and a trailing stop activation of 1% once it reaches the 2% target price. Please help, thanks very much.

So far I've managed to backtest with fixed Targets (% above price) and Fixed stops (% below price).

```
tp_inp = input(2, title='Take Profit %', type=float,step=.1)/100
sl_inp = input(1, title='Stop Loss %', type=float,step=.1)/100
trail_inp = input(1, title='Trailing %', type=float,step=.1)/100

stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)
trail_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - trail_inp)

strategy.entry("Long", true, when = buysignal == 1)

strategy.exit("Exit","Long", stop=stop_level, trail_price=take_level, trail_offset=trail_level)
```

I just can't wrap around my head to get the trailing stop work in the backtest. I am just able to do it with fixed stops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

leave only

```
strategy.exit("Long", stop=stop_level, trail_price=take_level, trail_offset=trail_level)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much I figured it out and logged in after a long long time. Haha thanks!!@!

Answer (score 0):

According to pine script reference [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit), trail_offset has to be specified in ticks. In your code, a price is specified for trail_offset.

A possible solution would be to get the min tick for the symbol with `syminfo.mintick` and  calculate how much 1% of the current price is in ticks:

```
trail_offset = int(close * trail_inp / syminfo.mintick)

strategy.exit("Exit","Long", stop=stop_level, trail_price=take_level, trail_offset=trail_offset)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben!